Where is the "Integrate tab for the HttpTrigger" located?
I am working through the azure function tutorial, here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/tutorial-custom-providers-function-setup
I'm to the section, "Install Azure Table storage bindings" and step one says "Go to the Integrate tab for the HttpTrigger."
I've searched in VSCode and Azure Portal, but, i'm not finding it.
Any pointers?
Thanks,
David


Where is the "Integrate tab for the HttpTrigger" located?

To find the Integration tab, firstly open Function App in Azure Portal. Then In Overview Section Click on Deployed or Created Function in Function App:

Then It will Show Like below

Click on Integration Tab to change or check the bindings:

